# how to have gpresult on remote comupter outputted as xml or html?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, group-policy, windows-command-prompt

I'm on a Windows 2016 server and I'm trying to get the RSOP from a Windows 2008 remote computer using the command GPRESULT. However when I use the command:

```
gpresult /S 10.0.52.234 /U Administrator /P !2Pwz%3<.2$ /SCOPE COMPUTER /X output.xml
```

I receive this error:

```
ERROR: Invalid Syntax. Options /U, /P, /R, /V, /Z cannot be specified along with /X, /H.
```

Is there a way to connect to a remote computer (using /u and /p) and output the RSOP in xml or html. (maybe import the policies into the destination server then use GPResult on the destination server so it would not require /u and /p)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the /X option cannot be used if you use the /U and /P options.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/gpresult

One workaround though would be to issue that command from a user that has access to the remote computer, that way, you wouldn't need to use the /U and /P options.

So your command would look like this, assuming you run it with a user that has access and the proper rights to 10.0.52.234.

```
gpresult /S 10.0.52.234 /SCOPE COMPUTER /X output.xml
```

Other than that, it is always possible to whip up a small PowerShell script that would connect to the remote computer, run gpresult, and then copy the report file to the desired system.

Comment: 1) how would I given a user access to the remote computer?

Comment: 2) powershell "get-gpresultantsetofpolicy" and module "grouppolicy" are not available on the destination servers, so I don't think I can powershell script it